# Need to split a string in bash after certain number of characters

Tags: string, bash, variables

I am writing a bash script that will execute a command and store the value in a string variable, now I need to split the string after certain characters. Is there a way? I cannot use delimiters coz the format is kinda like this

```
  PV Name /dev/sda2
  PV Size 10.39 GB
```

Here I need to get the /dev/sda2 and 10.39 GB(if possible, just 10.39 alone) and write it in a new file. I cannot use delimiter because the space is at first.. I have not done much bash scripting. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your delimiter constraint. Doesn't `awk '{print$3}'` work? If not, what about `$4` instead of `$3`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo "${var:8}"
```

will echo the contents of `$var` starting at the character 8 (zero-based).

To strip off anything starting at the first space:

```
data=${var:8}
echo "${data%% *}"
```

Answer (score 9):

To get only certain characters, use `cut`:

```
 $ echo '1234567' | cut -c2-5
 2345
```

However, in your case `awk` looks like better option:

```
$ echo '  PV Size 10.39 GB' | awk '{ print $3 }'
10.39
```

It reads text as space/tab separated columns, so it should work perfectly fine

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`cut`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29):

```
$ echo "PV Name /dev/sda2" |cut -d " " -f 3
/dev/sda2
```